# List attributes in field using ModelBuilder/ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I'm using ArcGis 10.2.2 and I'm creating a model in ModelBuilder.

I want to know how I can list the attributes of a field and then make a selection for each unique attribute using Python.

I have a shapefile with the field "Name". Example:

```
name | 
----------- 
BB 
BB 
AB 
AB 
C 
C
```

I want to list BB, AB, C, etc.

I want to construct a list and then use that list to make a selection for each of the unique values.  For example, "Name" = 'BB'.

Comment: Your question is confusing, you are mixing up terms between your title question and the body content (field vs attribute field values, modelbuilder or python?).

Comment: the goal is to automate the base is modelbuilder if there is no option to use a tool to perform this could be the use of Python Script

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with that clarification, please?  Also, can you describe in more detail what the inputs and outputs from your model/script would be?

Comment: thanks, this solved with the tool (Iterate Feature Selection)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000s000000) in ModelBuilder:

> Iterates over features in a feature class.

Comment: I do not understand I could explain

Comment: Click on the hyperlink for Iterate Feature Selection within may answer, it will provide you additional content and case examples.